# IntelliJ Generated Ant build results in broken code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant, path

I added JDK and Ant to Enviroment System variables but that doesn't stop a simple Ant build in IntelliJ from breaking. I have set the system path variable to accept both Ant's directory and the JDK enviroment. I have created JAVA_HOME and Java is still functioning in the cmd.

[image: broken code]

There isn't any code in the project. There is just this build that generates this default code.

I haven't altered anything once I started the build and if I go into Project Structure -> Project Settings, I have the Project SDK set to 1.8.

What is going on here?

**EDIT: I managed to remove a lot of the errors by toggling a box to Generate the Ant Build to Use current IDEA instane for idea.home property. **

Comment: So, unknown code causes unknown problem. And we're supposed to help, how?

Comment: This is the default code that pops up when you generate an Ant build. Maybe I missed something when installing everything?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like many properties from `test3.xml` are not available/defined in `module_test3.xml`. Did you already try to do a "Generate single-file ant build" (the second radio button in the "Generate Ant Build" dialog)? This could be a way to avoid the problem of Ant properties from one build file not being available in another build file.

Are you very attached to Ant for building your projects? You could give [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) and/or [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) a try, to see if these tools work better for you.

If you are doing Android development, you could also check out [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html). If you are using IntelliJ IDEA, I would definitively consider upgrading to [version 15](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download); the community edition is free and version 10.5 is around four years old now.